# How do I stretch an element to the left edge of the page when its parent is centered?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I need to position a colour which is 50px high but it goes from the middle container to the left end of the page.

Is there a position left width 100% type selector?

Here is the example, so you know what i mean...

[image]

The site fits into 960px wide but the solid color needs to stretch on the left side.

Comment: I don't understand what "position left width 100% type selector" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HjrcT/

```css
li, li:before {
    height: 25px;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background: #777
}
li:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    background: #f0f
}
```

IE7 [does not support `:before`](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent), so if you need it to work in that infernal browser, `:before` must be replaced with a `<span>`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HjrcT/1/

Comment: if forgot to mention i am using DIVs and using IE7

Comment: Are you serious? Fine, here you go, the IE7 version with only `div`s: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HjrcT/2/

Comment: i tried the first version that you made here: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HjrcT/ but when you create another LI it at add another megenta colored block becomes larger. I just want it for the first li.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach using a 50% width div that sits behind the container. The color of the bar lines up with the menu div and creates the illusion that they're one-and-the-same.

http://jsfiddle.net/F74cT/1/